# Denver airport public transport

Tags: usa, airport-transfer, denver, den

I know there is a public bus from the Denver International Airport to the Market street. I tried to figure out the schedule, but was not able to find it. Does anyone know where I can find it?

Is this a good (decent) option for getting to the city of Denver from the airport?

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://www.rtd-denver.com/skyride.shtml.  As far as being a good option you might want to list the criteria for good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www3.rtd-denver.com/schedules/getRouteList.action?routeType=9

The link above has schedules for buses departing from DEN airport into the city. Depending on where you want to go, click on the bus route for timing information (if you want to go to Market street, you probably want bus AS, then transfer at Stapleton to bus 38). For more route information, you can go to maps.google.com and use the public transportation option.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I think I should use the AF line to the Civic Center Station, though.

Comment: @Dan yes that would probably be simpler :) You're welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Since April 2016, the [RTD A Line](http://www.rtd-denver.com/a-line.shtml) is now in operation.  This is a direct rail line from Denver International Airport to downtown Denver (Union Station).

The airport rail station is at the south end of the main terminal.  There are trains every 15 minutes most of the day, going to every 30 minutes after 6:30pm and early mornings.   There are departures from the airport until after 1:00 am.  The journey to downtown takes 37 minutes with no transfers.  Luggage racks are available on the train.

The regular fare is $10.50 and is sold as a day pass, including unlimited rail and bus travel throughout the RTD system for the whole day.  Tickets can be bought at a machine on the platform using cash or credit card, or using a phone app.  There are [discounts](http://www.rtd-denver.com/DiscountFares.shtml#proof) for youths, seniors, people with disabilities, and certain other categories, but you may need to have appropriate ID or documentation.

(For marketing purposes, the line is branded as the "University of Colorado A Line".  Its Union Station terminus is reasonably close to the [University of Colorado Denver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Colorado_Denver), but travelers should note that the line does not serve the university's better-known [Boulder flagship campus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Colorado_Boulder).)

Market Street is three blocks southeast of Union Station.